# Ef Core generic repository include nested navigation properties

Tags: c#, ef-core-7.0

I am using unit of work with repository pattern and I use this method to get direct navigation properties

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllIncluding(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
{
        IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;
        return await includes.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include)).ToListAsync();
}
```

and I use it like this

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<SomeEntity>> GetAllDetailsAsync()
{
    var data = await unitOfWork.Service.GetAllIncluding(
                    x => x.DirectNavigation1,
                    x => x.DirectNavigation2,
                    x => x.DirectNavigation3) ;
}
```

I try to use

> x => x.DirectNavigation3.Select(o => o.NestedNavigation1)
> But then I got a error.

In order to do this, I had to change my params to

> GetAllIncluding(params string[] includes)
> with the same implementation no change at all

**The code works just fine but I don't like work with string  due to its difficulty in maintenance**
Please share any alternative ways of including nested navigation properties without using string.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: A DbContext is already a generic multi-entity repository and Unit-of-Work. A DbSet is already a generic single-entity repository. Why do you think you need *another* repository over the repository? `difficulty in maintenance` that's what you get by putting another repo over the repo.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I already regret using unit of work with repository pattern. But I can't change my code right now

Comment: The question is still *not* about repositories. You can use `AutoInclude()` in the model configuration to automatically eagerly load navigations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real question seems to be how to load all related properties. This has nothing to do with repositories. A DbContext already is a multi-entity repository and Unit-of-Work anyway.

EF Core 6 added the ability to [automatically load navigations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#model-configuration-for-auto-including-navigations) by using the `AutoInclude()` call in the model :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Theme>().Navigation(e => e.ColorScheme).AutoInclude();
```

This can be turned off in queries with `IgnoreAutoIncludes()`, eg

```
var themes = context.Themes.IgnoreAutoIncludes().ToList();
```

It's not possible to chain `Include` calls from `Expression<Func<T, object>>` expressions. In LINQ the expressions are ... expressions that specify properties or code that eventually gets translated to something else. They aren't functions that get called. Besides, specifying all those expressions would take as many lines as chaining `Include` methods and look uglier.

In `.Include(theme=>theme.ColorScheme)` the expression isn't returning the value of `ColorScheme`. The `Expression<Func<TEntity,TProperty>>` is used to [find the correct property to use using reflection](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore/Extensions/EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.cs#L2301) :

```
public static IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TProperty> Include<TEntity, TProperty>(
    this IQueryable<TEntity> source,
    Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> navigationPropertyPath)
    where TEntity : class
{
    Check.NotNull(navigationPropertyPath, nameof(navigationPropertyPath));

    return new IncludableQueryable<TEntity, TProperty>(
        source.Provider is EntityQueryProvider
            ? source.Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(
                Expression.Call(
                    instance: null,
                    method: IncludeMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TEntity), typeof(TProperty)),
                    arguments: new[] { source.Expression, Expression.Quote(navigationPropertyPath) }))
            : source);
}
```